# If $(G, \oplus)$ has order $2n$, prove that every proper subgroup of $(G, \oplus)$

Tags: group-theory

These questions are really bothering me. Any help would be much appreciated.

Let $p$ be prime

a) If $(G, \oplus)$ has order $2p$, prove that every proper subgroup of $(G, \oplus)$ is cyclic

b) If $(G, \oplus)$ has order $p^2$, prove that $(G, \oplus)$ has a subgroup of order $p$

Comment: Your question a) is not complete.

Comment: The first question is at this moment incomplete. For the second, suppose $a$ is not the identity element, and let $H$ be the subgroup generated by $a$. If $H$ is not all of $G$, we are finished. And if $H$ is all of $G$ we are almost finished.

Comment: @AndréNicolas I'm not understanding your comment.  Why does $\langle a\rangle\ne G$ imply $|H|=n$?  Is it something to do with the notation $\oplus$?

Comment: @TimRaczkowski:  For any $H$ and $G$, if $H$ is a subgroup of $G$ then the order of $H$ divides the order of $G$. Since $n$ is prime, $n^2$ has only the divisors $1$, $n$, and $n^2$. The  order of $<a>$ is not $1$, since $a$ is not the identity. It is not $n^2$, since by assumption $<a>$ is a proper subgroup of $G$. So the order of $<a>$ must be $n$.

Comment: Oh, I see.  I missed the assumption that $n$ was prime. :)

Comment: sorry about that guys a) was supposed to be If $(G, \oplus)$ has order $2n$, prove that every proper subgroup of $(G, \oplus)$ is cyclic

Comment: The canon (especially in group theory) is to use '$p$' and '$q$' for prime integers; I've gone ahead and swapped your $n$ here for a $p$ to make it clearer.

Answer (score 1):

(a) If $H$ is a proper subgroup of $G$, then the order of $H$ is a divisor of $2n$.

If $n$ is prime, the only possible divisors of $2n$ are $1, 2, n$ or $2n$. Since the last one is not possible,....

(b) Let $x \in G$ be $x \neq e$. Then the order of $x$ is a divisor of $n^2$, thus $1,n$ or $n^2$. The order cannot be $1$.

If the order of $x$ is $n$ then $<x>$ is the desired subgroup.

If the order of $x$ is $n^2$, find the right power of $x$ which has order $n$ and go back to the previous case [ alternately use that $G$ is cyclic, and prove that a cyclic group has the desired property].